# Change style of a child control on MouseOver in WPF

Tags: wpf, properties, styles, controls, rectangles

I have a custom control that holds two Rectangles and several TextBoxes. I wish to change the background color of the Rectangle on MouseOver.

I add trigger as following:

```
  <Rectangle 
            Grid.Column="1" 
            Fill="#FF383838" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
            Margin="0,4,4,4">

            <Rectangle.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FF383838" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FF575757" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Rectangle.Style>

        </Rectangle>
```

But since rectangle is part of my control, I assume the event is not firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a property via XAML will be applied over the style properties that you try to set.  To fix this, remove `Fill=#FF383838` so you should have:

```
<Rectangle Grid.Column="1"
           Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
           Margin="0,4,4,4">
//... rest of code here
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle" x:Key="test">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FF383838" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FF575757" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource test}" />
```